# Login form using JSON

Tags: java, android, authentication, json

i am trying to make a login form by connecting to my database and verifying username and password, i am using JSON method

```
 public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
 JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
 private static String url_login = "http://192.168.1.81:80get_all_usernames.php";
 JSONArray admin = null;
 int i;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adminlogin);
}


 public void enter(View v)
 {

      TextView user= (TextView) findViewById (R.id.user);
      TextView pass= (TextView) findViewById (R.id.pass);
      CharSequence usr=  user.getText();
      CharSequence pwd=pass.getText();
      Log.i("",""+usr);
      Log.i("",""+pwd);
      ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "GET",param);

      Log.i("","fjefejjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
     try{
       int success = json.getInt("success");

       if(success == 1){
    admin = json.getJSONArray("admin");
        for(i=0;i<admin.length();i++){
        final JSONObject c = admin.getJSONObject(i);
        String real_user=c.getString("username");
        String real_password= c.getString("password");
            if(usr==real_user && pwd==real_password)
            {
     Log.i("success","login sucessfull-----------------------");
        }
     else{
       Log.i("fail","Login failed ----------------------------------");
         }
     }}
    }catch(Exception e){
      }
   }

      }
```

It keeps returning an error at the line: 
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "GET",param);
can someone please help me with that?

Thank you in advance,
Ralph

Comment: There is a / missing in your url => http://192.168.1.81:80/get_all_usernames.php

Comment: this isn't the problem, probably made a mistake when pasting it here. there is a problem with the line  JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "GET",param); i don't know why...

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is wrong:

```
http://192.168.1.81:80get_all_usernames.php
```

should be:

```
http://192.168.1.81:80/get_all_usernames.php
```

Also, for http you do not need to specify port 80.  That is the default.

Answer (score 1):

First of All Correct your URL and then
Use HttpClient and AsynsTask for Network Request.

```
public final class HttpTask extends  AsyncTask<Strin param, Void param, String param> {

private HttpClient mHc = new DefaultHttpClient();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost request = new Http(params[0]);
   try
   {
       // Add params using Name Value Pair

       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
       //Parse Response from InputStream  
   }

   // return  "Success" or "fail";
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... progress) {


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

}
```

}